# Vimeo SSL error using Retrofit on Android

Tags: android, ssl, retrofit, vimeo-api

I have a problem with `Vimeo API` using Retrofit. My point is to upload `MultipartTypedOutput` on Vimeo using `Retrofit`. 
Here is some code:

```
public interface VimeoUploadApi {
    @PUT("/upload")
    void uploadVideo(@Header("Authorization") String header,
                     @Body MultipartTypedOutput body,
                     @Query("ticket_id") String ticket_id,
                     BaseCallback<VideoUploadedEvent> callback);
}
public VimeoUploadApi provideVimeoUploadApi(String url) {
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(url)
                .setLogLevel(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL : RestAdapter.LogLevel.NONE)
                .build();

    return restAdapter.create(VimeoUploadApi.class);
}

private MultipartTypedOutput generateMultipartObject() {
    MultipartTypedOutput multipartTypedOutput = new MultipartTypedOutput();
    File file = new File(videoPath);
    long totalSize = file.length();
    FileProgressListener listener = new FileProgressListener(totalSize);
    listener.setPath(videoPath);
    multipartTypedOutput.addPart("video", new CountingTypedFile("video/mp4", file, listener));
    return multipartTypedOutput;
}
```

And call:

```
provideVimeoUploadApi(getUploadUrl(secure_link)).uploadVideo(
    "Authorization: Bearer " + Environment.VIMEO_TOKEN,
    generateMultipartObject(),
    event.getTicket_id(),
    new BaseCallback<VideoUploadedEvent>()
);
```

And when I upload my video, I get an error like this:

> Write error: ssl=0x98cc2800: I/O error during system call, Connection
>   reset by peer
>       retrofit.RetrofitError: Write error: ssl=0x98cc2800: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
>
> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0x98cc2800:
>   I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer

Anyway to fix it?

Comment: Where does this CountingTypedFile comme from ? I can't find it in retrofit. Could you also add the code for your getUploadUrl(secure_link) method ?

Comment: Can you add any more code? have you had any success [checking the user's quota](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#check-users-quota) to make sure that you're using the OAuth properly?

Comment: I just go away from Retofit and use simple HttpUrlConnection. Now it is work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, due to I not found any solution to send videos to `Vimeo` using `Retrofit`, I found that old-good `HttpUrlConnection` works pretty nice.
If anyone need some code, I will post it here.